# Why transpose of independent feature matrix is necessary in case of linear regression?

Tags: linear-regression, linear-algebra

I can follow classical linear regression steps:

$Xw=y$

$X^{-1}Xw=X^{-1}y$

$Iw=X^{-1}y$

$w=X^{-1}y$

However, on implementing in Python, I see that instead of simply using

```
w = inv(X).dot(y)
```

they apply

```
w = inv(X.T.dot(X)).dot(X.T).dot(y)
```

What is the explanation of the transpositions and the two times multiplication here? I'm confused...

Answer (score 1):

OLS (linear regression) would be solved by:

$$ (X‘X)^{-1} X‘y = \hat{\beta}. $$

Assuming a matrix $X$ (with the first column equal to 1 for each row to emulate the intercept) and vector $y$ in Python, you can solve $\hat{\beta}$ by:

```
np.linalg.inv(X.T @ X) @ X.T @ y
```

Answer (score 0):

That answer comes from the set of weights $w$ (or $\theta$) that analytically solves the cost function which is defined to be

$J(\theta) = (X\theta - y)^T (X\theta - y)$

(See [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/optimization-of-supervised-learning-loss-function-under-the-hood-df1791391c82) for more info)

Expanding the cost function we get

$J(\theta) = \theta^TX^TX\theta - 2 y^TX\theta + y^Ty$

(Note that all three terms come out to be scalers)

Before we take the next step, we need to brush up on derivatives of matrices

*Some common matrix derivative formulas for reference:*

$\frac{\partial (AX)}{\partial X} = A^T \ ;\  \frac{\partial (X^TA)}{\partial X} = A \ ;\ \frac{\partial (X^TX)}{\partial X} = 2X \ ;\ \frac{\partial (X^TAX)}{\partial X} = AX+A^TX$

Using those rules we can take the derivative of the cost function with respect to $\theta$

$\frac{\partial J(\theta)}{\partial \theta} = 2 X^TX \theta - 2 X^Ty$

Setting this to 0 we get

$2 X^TX\theta - 2 X^T y = 0$

solving for $\theta$ we get

$\theta = (X^TX)^{-1} X^T y$

Written in code that's

```
w = inv(X.T.dot(X)).dot(X.T).dot(y)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure is not correct. You are using the inverse (which does not exist in the general case). You have to use the transpose.

$$y=X\beta$$
$$X^Ty=X^TX\beta$$
$$
\hat{\beta} = [X^TX]^{-1}X^Ty$$

You might be asking why we multiplied with the transpose. In general you data matrix $X$ is not square, hence it is not invertible. In order to get something with square format/dimension we multiplied with $X^T$. If $X$ has $n$ rows (observations) and $m$ columns (features, inputs) then the transpose has $m$ rows and $n$ columns. Hence $X^TX$ is squared with $m \times m$ as its dimension. In most situations we can invert this product.